# How to toggle the lable of an action button in R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I wanted to create a button that initially show this label "Start Button".
After you click it, it will change the label to "hide", if you press it again it will change to "Show".

I couldn't find any help anywhere. Hope this help someone.

This is the solution that works for me.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("hide_bt", "Start Input"),
  textOutput("text2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  hidvar1 <- reactiveValues(vari1 = 1)
  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$hide_bt)){
      input$hide_bt
      isolate({
        if (hidvar1$vari1 == 1) {
          hidvar1$vari1 <- 2
        } else if (hidvar1$vari1 == 2) {
          hidvar1$vari1 <- 1
        }
      })
    }
  })
  
  label <- reactive({
    if (!is.null(input$hide_bt)) {
      if (hidvar1$vari1 == 1) {
        label <- "Hide"
      } else if (hidvar1$vari1 == 2) {
        label <- "Show"
      }
    }
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$hide_bt, {
    updateActionButton(session,"hide_bt", label = label())
  })
  
  
  output$text2 <- renderText({ 
    paste(hidvar1$vari1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code by moving the `if` conditions into the `observeEvent`:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("hide_bt", "Start Input"),
  textOutput("text2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  hidvar1 <- reactiveValues(vari1 = 1)
  
  observeEvent(input$hide_bt, {
    if (hidvar1$vari1 == 1) {
      label <- "Hide"
      hidvar1$vari1 <- 2
    } else {
      label <- "Show"
      hidvar1$vari1 <- 1
    }
    
    updateActionButton(session, "hide_bt", label = label)
  })
  
  output$text2 <- renderText({ 
    paste(hidvar1$vari1)
  })
}
```